Ideal approach to visualise cost replacement migrating from vendor A to B
I'm trying to wrap my head around how to approach my task.
I have vendor A who is deeply integrated in my organisation and I am replacing them with vendor B.
I'd like to show where I am cutting down on vendor A the cost decreases but increases with vendor B as they take over that output.
I thought maybe a burndown chart but wondering if there's a specific method that I can research? Kind of like a quasi-burn down to burn up chart?
Hopefully I am making sense. Looking forward to any suggestions I can get.
Thanks


Kind of like a quasi-burn down to burn up chart?

You can achieve that by a stacked column chart, like this:

Here is the JSFiddle if you want to play with it https://jsfiddle.net/y4djftv9/4/

Ah this is a great idea. Thank you so much!
